# Collect multiple buttons

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I have a couple of buttons and want to collect them in a HBox and set them in a vertical row. The goal is something similar to this formation: http://vandelaydesign.com/images/navi/vertical.gif

```
Button addButton = new Button("Add Expense");
addButton.setOnAction(new AddExpenseGUI(rootStage, data));

Button editButton = new Button("Edit");
addButton.setOnAction(new EditButtonListener());
```

I tried multiple things. This was one idea of me, but I just get a horizontal formation:

```
HBox a = new HBox();
a.getChildren().addALL(addButton, editButton);
grid.add(a,0,0);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The H in HBox stands for Horizontal so the Pane you are looking for is VBox (for Vertical)

See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG

Answer (score 2):

Use a [VBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) and skin your buttons. See these:
[Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)
[Styling FX Buttons with CSS](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/)